# Apache Tomcat's error page

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, custom-error-pages

I am using Apache Tomcat v7.0.63 which is hosting 4 different applications. One of the applications has the list of Error pages.

Now we want to make it generic so that the other applications too can make use of the same error pages. In this way, we do not need to keep duplicate files in all the web applications. We want to keep all the error pages somewhere under tomcat/errorPages directory or tomcat/conf/errorPages directory.

I tried modifying /tomcat/webapps/MyApplication/WEB-INF/web.xml file as below and it is not working. Can anyone please help?

```
</error-page>
    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/../../errorPages/errorPage404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And errorPage404.html is placed in /tomcat/errorPages directory.

Comment: Hi did you check below solution

Comment: Yes. It did not work.

1. I have verified the file permissions too. 
2. I have tried using absolute path too. 
3. I have tried using regEx too.. like <location>/*file_not_found.html</location>

Answer (score 4):

Since Apache Tomcat version 9.0, you may define the ErrorValve on your server.xml under your Host definition with errorCode.nnn (where nnn is the HTTP error code) pointing to a UTF-8 encoded HTML page, as described at [configuration information](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve).

So, your server.xml should include on your main host:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost">
    <!-- ... your other configs ... -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" errorCode.404="<path to your html, may be relative to $CATALINA_HOME or absolute>"/>
</Host>
```

This avoids the need to define a different error page on every project or to include a global ROOT.war with error pages defined on global web.xml, as stated in the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to make generic, I suggest you to define the errors in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml` . It will override default  error pages that come with `Tomcat`.

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/server_error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/file_not_found.html</location>
    </error-page>
```

Make sure to move the error pages to location `/webapps/ROOT/`