# Spring framework custom 404 error specific case

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am able to get the Custom 404 Error Page if I include webApp root directory `myweb` in the URL path -

```
http://localhost/myweb/users/david
```

[image: Custom 404 Error Page]

I added the following entry in web.xml to get custom 404 page -

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/pageNotFound.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

However, I am still getting Spring default 404 Error Page when I hit the following URL -

```
http://localhost/users/david
```

[image: Spring 404 Error Page]

Why it is not working without webApp root directory in the URL path? Is there any way to get same custom 404 Not Found Page for this as well?

**EDIT:**

My relevant web.xml code -

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myweb</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.gridpoint.energy.web.common.servlet.listeners.RequestContextInitializer</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>
<!-- Dispatch Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>services-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>services-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>services-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/applications/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>services-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/healthCheck</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/pageNotFound.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

Comment: I think your first request reaches tomcat's "default" servlet, which responds with the default error page.

Comment: @Barracuda - So I need another web.xml on top of project root to get custom 404 page for it?

Comment: I am not sure how to change tomcat's default error page( and if that's even the case here). Wait for others to answer. As far as I know, your default error page defined in web.xml effects all servlets you define in your application but not tomcat's one. Again, not 100% sure. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869500/apache-tomcats-error-page

Answer (score -2):

In my case I created customer controller **ErrorController** using Spring mvc 4.

I set next configuration web.xml.

```
<error-page>
    <location>/errors</location>
</error-page>
```

Next. I created the controller. I shared the class. (ModelAndView is the path of my .jsp (exception/errorPage)).

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, ModelMap model) {
         
        ModelAndView errorPage = new ModelAndView("exception/errorPage");
        String errorMsg = "";
        String customerMsg = "";
        
        int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(httpRequest);
 
        switch (httpErrorCode) {
            case 400: {
                errorMsg     = "Http Error Code: 400. Bad Request";
                customerMsg  = "";
                break;
            }
            case 401: {
                errorMsg     = "Http Error Code: 401. Unauthorized";
                customerMsg  = "";
                break;
            }
            case 403: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 403. access denied";
                customerMsg  = "";
                break;
            }
            case 404: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 404. Resource not found";
                customerMsg  = "";
                break;
            }
            case 500: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 500. Internal Server Error";
                customerMsg  = "";
                break;
            }
        }
      
        errorPage.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);
        errorPage.addObject("customerMsg", customerMsg);
        return errorPage;
    }
     
    private int getErrorCode(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (Integer) httpRequest
          .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    }
}
```

Shared the basic errorPage.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>${errorMsg}</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>${customerMsg}</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this example to help you.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me. The issue is the absence of webApp root directory `myweb` (in the URL) in my case. Otherwise all these solutions will work.