# Tomcat 8.x | Global Error Page does not work

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, custom-error-pages

Trying to set up a global error page for all errors and all apps in /webapps.

**../conf/web.xml**

```
<web-app> 
...
  <error-page>
       <location>/error.html</location>
  </error-page>
...
</web-app>
```

**../webapps/ROOT/**

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mee mee 5 Feb  2 14:11 error.html
```

But that does not work.
If I put the error.html in the respective apps in /webapps, then of course it works. But my goal is to have one central error page for all apps.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: add in webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml also

Comment: @PavanKumarTS: That didn't work.

Comment: specify error codes https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869762/7887883

Comment: @PavanKumarTS: No, didn't work, too. You don't need to specify. In case of any error, error.html will be displayed.