# Create Tomcat custom error pages, but not in ROOT

Tags: java, tomcat, custom-error-pages

Can I put my generic error folder not in the /ROOT folder, but somewhere else?

I'm running a local Tomcat server (9.0.37) with multiple applications, similar to the folder structure below

```
tomcat/
      conf/
         web.xml
         server.xml
      webapps/
         ROOT/
           WEB-INF/
         app1/
           META-INF/
           WEB-INF/
              web.xml
         app2/
           META-INF/
           WEB-INF/
              web.xml
```

I'm trying to create some custom error pages to supersede the default Tomcat ones; generic ones that can be shared by all applications.

I've consulted [a](https://serverfault.com/questions/254102/custom-error-pages-on-apache-tomcat) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869500/apache-tomcats-error-page) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914575/how-to-build-server-level-custom-error-page-in-tomcat) [examples](https://rajesh-w61.medium.com/custom-error-pages-apache-tomcat-2aee835d81bc) on this and have created an `/errors` folder, containing the HTML for my error pages, as well as modifying the `tomcat/conf/web.xml`

```xml
<error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code> <!-- Not Found -->
    <location>/errors/error_404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

and the `tomcat/conf/server.xml`

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
       error.400="errors/error_400.html"
       error.404="errors/error_404.html" showReport="false"
       showServerInfo="false" />
```

The issue here is that after deployment and simulating a 404 error, I get something alone the lines of "Page Not Found".

My `/errors` folder was initially parked under `tomcat/` (basically, on the same level as `conf/`), but I moved it around to try and figure out the cause of this issue.

After moving around the path of my folder, it turns out that the settings in the two XML files(or at least, based on `conf/web.xml` from what I'm seeing) seems to be pointing towards to `conf/webapps/ROOT/errors`.

In other words, it works if I add my `/errors` folder to `conf/webapps/ROOT/`. This is consistent with the answers I found above.

This is not what I want. I do not want my error folder to be in the ROOT folder, but in another more generic path, as mentioned above under `/tomcat`

I had even tried something like the full path itself

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code> <!-- Not Found -->
    <location>/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/webapps/errors/error_404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

and I still get the 'Page not Found' error.

I also had tried, as per one of the answers linked above, starting the path with `./`

```xml
<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code> <!-- Not Found -->
     <location>./errors/error_404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

and all I got was the server complaining that the URL must start with a forward slash('/').

Trying `/../errors/error_404.html` didn't really help either.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Welp....I found out where I went wrong.

The `conf/server.xml`

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
       error.400="errors/error_400.html"
       error.404="errors/error_404.html" showReport="false"
       showServerInfo="false" />
```

error.404 -> error**Code**.404

error.400 -> error**Code**.400

Not sure if I read the documentation wrong, or the site I was reading it from had the wrong syntax, but once I changed that, my issues were more or less solved. This not only referred to the error pages in the base `/tomcat` directory as I wanted, but also allowed referencing to other folders, like `/tomcat/webapps` for example.